# Specifying timeout when restoring nuget packages

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, myget

In Nuget, is there a way to specify a timeout value when executing the nuget restore command? I would like to increase the default timeout (not sure what it is) - since I'm getting a lot of request timeout errors.

Comment: No, there isn't.  Generally people have the opposite problem in that NuGet gets an HTTP timeout while trying to restore the package.

Comment: One thing you can do if you are finding the response time of NuGet Package Restore to be too slow, is to create your own NuGet repository locally and put the packages on that repository instead.  This is also usually a good idea to better control individual developers going rogue and just updating from the NuGet public site, perhaps introducing regression issues between versions.